# How to hide Electron.js menubar

Tags: electron

I'm trying to remove the Electron menubar from my window. I use this

```
myWindow.isMenuBarVisible(false);
```

But this doesn't work. Setting the 'AutoHideMenuBar' property works but that only hides the menu until the alt key is pressed.

What is the proper way to remove the Electron menubar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot alter visiblity of the menu with [isMenuBarVisible()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winismenubarvisible). It can only tell you if menu is visible or not.

> `isMenuBarVisible()` Returns Boolean - Whether the menu bar is visible.

Try [setMenu(null)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows).

> `setMenu(menu)` Sets the `menu` as the window's menu bar, setting it to `null` will remove
>   the menu bar.

Answer (score 7):

I am using electron version 10.
For me, I added parameter to hide menubar on BrowserWindow()

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height:600,
        autoHideMenuBar: true //hide menu bar
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no property in the `options` object to completely hide the menu bar, but you can use this instance property after `BrowserWindow` creation:

```
win.removeMenu() // Remove the window's menu bar.
```

Works fine for Windows and Linux

*Source*: [Electron API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do.

```
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
```